# Android Gallery doesn't support streamed files

Tags: android, stream, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver

In my app the user can select files and open them in the appropriate app (using an ACTION_VIEW intent).
I need to do some work on the data before giving it to the other app. So I'm using a streaming solution : I implemented a ContentProvider that implements `openTypedAssetFile` and `writeDataToPipe` (this method fills the output ParcelFileDescriptor created by `openPipeHelper`).

This works : I can open .pdf files, .txt files etc. The streaming seems correct.
I can open images usings 3-party apps.
However when I open an image using the `Gallery`, it doesn't work (Gallery shows a black screen), and I get the following exception :

```
fail to open myfile.jpg
UriImage(21890): java.io.FileNotFoundException: Not a whole file
```

I had a look at the Gallery source ([here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Gallery2/+/kitkat-release/src/com/android/gallery3d/data/UriImage.java)) and I could see that the exception is thrown here :

```
        try {
            if (MIME_TYPE_JPEG.equalsIgnoreCase(mContentType)) {
                InputStream is = mApplication.getContentResolver()
                        .openInputStream(mUri);
                mRotation = Exif.getOrientation(is);
                Utils.closeSilently(is);
            }
            **mFileDescriptor = mApplication.getContentResolver()
                    .openFileDescriptor(mUri, "r");**
            if (jc.isCancelled()) return STATE_INIT;
            return STATE_DOWNLOADED;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.w(TAG, "fail to open: " + mUri, e);
            return STATE_ERROR;
        }
```

However, once in the Gallery app, if I select "Set as wallpaper", then I can see my image, it is then well streamed. So the problem appears when Gallery opens.

After a deeper look (in the ContentResolver code etc.) I couldn't understand why it behaves this way. It seems that `Gallery` does not support streaming files. Is that right ?
Do you have any idea ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: you create your own gallery then access selected images, https://github.com/luminousman/MultipleImagePick

Answer (score -1):

```
            String scheme = mUri.getScheme();

            ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();

            // If we are sent file://something or
            // content://org.openintents.filemanager/mimetype/something...
            if (scheme.equals("file")
                    || (scheme.equals("content") && fileUri
                            .getEncodedAuthority().equals(
                                    "org.openintents.filemanager"))) {

                // Get the path
                filePath = fileUri.getPath();

                // Trim the path if necessary
                // openintents filemanager returns
                // content://org.openintents.filemanager/mimetype//mnt/sdcard/xxxx.jpg
                if (filePath.startsWith("/mimetype/")) {
                    String trimmedFilePath = filePath
                            .substring("/mimetype/".length());
                    filePath = trimmedFilePath.substring(trimmedFilePath
                            .indexOf("/"));
                }
              } else if (scheme.equals("content")) {

                // If we are given another content:// URI, look it up in the
                // media provider

                filePath = getFilePathFromContentUri(fileUri,
                        contentResolver);

            } else {

                Log.e("filePath--------->>>>>", filePath + "");
            }
```

and

```
    private String getFilePathFromContentUri(Uri selectedVideoUri,
        ContentResolver contentResolver) {
    String filePathString;
    String[] filePathColumn = { MediaColumns.DATA };

    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(selectedVideoUri, filePathColumn,
            null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
    filePathString = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
    cursor.close();
    return filePathString;
  }
```

and now use this filepath ..

```
   try {
        if (MIME_TYPE_JPEG.equalsIgnoreCase(mContentType)) {
            InputStream is = mApplication.getContentResolver()
                    .openInputStream(filePath);  // ** change is here 
            mRotation = Exif.getOrientation(is);
            Utils.closeSilently(is);
        }
        ** mFileDescriptor = mApplication.getContentResolver()
                .openFileDescriptor(filePath, "r"); **
        if (jc.isCancelled()) return STATE_INIT;
        return STATE_DOWNLOADED;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.w(TAG, "fail to open: " + mUri, e);
        return STATE_ERROR;
    }
```

this is work for me

Comment: I'm sorry but your codes does not answer to the original question at all. The original question is about streaming data from an app to another to open a file through a ContentProvider that streams it.